# Ana, lanza el balón a la canasta

Tags: pronombres, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

My quest to understand the relationship between prepositional phrases and indirect object pronouns continues.

[In this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=0lb3DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q&f=false), I find the example sentence

> Ana, lanza el balón a la canasta.
> (Ana, shoot the ball in the basket.)

I'm not good with the imperative, but it seems like that means that the following is correct:

> Ana lanza el balón a la canasta.
> (Ana shoots the ball in the basket.)

If I'm right about that, can I say this?

> Ana le lanza el balón.
> (Ana shoots the ball in it [the basket].)

If that's wrong, is there something similar that I could say? I want to replace "a la canasta" with a pronoun, if that is possible. And I want to not replace "el balón" with a pronoun.

Comment: Ana shoots the ball at the basket, in English. It does in or does not go in. Ana le lanza el ballon means: Ana throws the ball to him. lanzar algo a alguien.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie. Is there any other way that I could replace "a la canasta" with a pronoun? Or maybe an adverb?

Comment: @Lambie that's a great answer. If you post that first comment as the answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagina que estas viendo un partido de baloncesto y el comentarista dice....

Ana, lanza el balón a canasta // Ana, lanza el balón hacia (la) canasta.

- "Ana la lanza...y..." (el comentarista supone que se lanza el balón hacia la canasta desde cualquier punto, que es lo que estamos viendo en TV)
- "Ana lo lanza" (hace más bien referencia al balón, se supone que lanza el balón desde un punto concreto, quizás desde el punto de penalización o quizás hacia un compañero sin saber muy bien quien va a recoger el balón (quien lo va a recoger))
- Ana le lanza el balón. (más bien hace referencia a un compañero de equipo).

Comment: Thanks @DIego, that makes sense! From the various answers I have been getting, it sounds like "le" is almost never used to replace "a [x]" unless [x] is "alive" in some way. Is that right?

Comment: Cuando el pronombre desempeña la función de complemento indirecto, deben usarse las formas le, les (singular y plural, respectivamente), con independencia del género de la palabra a la que se refiera el pronombre: Le pedí disculpas a mi madre. Le dije a su hermana que viniera. Les di un regalo a los niños. Hay que tener cuidado con el "leísmo". RAE https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo

Comment: Is that also the rule when the indirect object is not a person? I can't think of an example. Maybe "she stole money from a bank"/"she stole money from it", or "he sent a letter to Paris"/"he sent a letter to it/there"?

Comment: Ella robo dinero de un banco / Ella lo robo - El envió una carta a París / El la envió. A pesar de la aparente simplicidad del sistema, existen casos excepcionales o aparentemente excepcionales dentro de la norma, así como una enorme variedad en cuanto a los usos efectivos en las distintas zonas hispanohablantes.  Información pormenorizada, pueden consultarse los artículos leísmo, laísmo y loísmo.

Comment: Debido a su extensión entre hablantes cultos y escritores de prestigio, se admite el uso de le en lugar de lo en función de complemento directo cuando el referente es una persona de sexo masculino: «Tu padre no era feliz. [...] Nunca le vi alegre» (TBallester Filomeno [Esp. 1988]). Sin embargo, el uso de les por los cuando el referente es plural, aunque no carece de ejemplos literarios, no está tan extendido como cuando el referente es singular, por lo que se desaconseja en el habla culta: «Casi nunca les vi con chicas»

Comment: El leísmo no se admite de ningún modo en la norma culta cuando el referente es inanimado: El libro que me prestaste le leí de un tirón; Los informes me les mandas cuando puedas. Y tampoco se admite, en general, cuando el referente es una mujer: Le consideran estúpida, aunque existen algunos casos en que el leísmo femenino de persona no se considera incorrecto  4f y g). https://www.rae.es/dpd/le%C3%ADsmo

Comment: 3. El leísmo, al igual que otros fenómenos paralelos relacionados con el uso antietimológico de los pronombres átonos de tercera persona (→ laísmo y loísmo), surge en Castilla durante la Edad Media. Todos estos fenómenos parecen deberse al nacimiento, en época temprana de la evolución del castellano, de una tendencia que, a diferencia de lo que ocurría en latín, en lugar de distinguir funciones gramaticales a través de las distintas formas pronominales —le(s) para el complemento indirecto y lo(s), la(s) para el complemento directo—

Comment: ... tiende a diferenciar entre masculino y femenino, por un lado, y entre persona y cosa por otro; también influye en muchos casos la condición de contable o no contable del referente.  Muy a grandes rasgos, la distribución, en este nuevo sistema, sería la siguiente: le(s) para el masculino de persona; lo(s) para el masculino de cosa, y la(s) para el femenino de persona y de cosa.

Comment: ...a) Los verbos llamados de «afección psíquica» —los que designan procesos que afectan al ánimo o producen acciones o reacciones emotivas, como afectar, asustar, asombrar, convencer, divertir, impresionar, molestar, ofender, perjudicar, preocupar, etc.—, dependiendo de distintos factores, admiten el uso de los pronombres de acusativo —lo(s), la(s)— y de los pronombres de dativo —le(s)—.

Answer (score 1):

Ana shoots the ball at the basket, in English. It goes in or does not go in.

However, Ana **le lanza** el ballon means: Ana **throws the ball to him**. lanzar algo a alguien.

Think about the English for a moment: She shoots the ball at the basket.

You can't replace "at the basket" with anything and still have the same sentence.

And shoot in basketball is really **tirar**, not **lanzar**. Though lanzar (lanzamiento) can be used too.

lanzar un tiro: to shoot a basket

Ana lanza un tiro a la canasta. Ana shoots a basketball.

Comment: lambie, Ana lanza a canasta / Ana tira a canasta. En fútbol, Ana lanza a portería / Ana tira a puerta.

Comment: Diego, vale. :)